# Python Pandas: Convert 2 fields Date + Time to 1 Datetime field

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

In a Pandas dataframe there are 2 columns:

```
"CREATED ON DATE" (dtype: datetime64[ns]) e.g. 2019-06-16
"CREATED AT TIME" (dtype: object) e.g. 19:46:14
```

Because of the type mismatch simply adding the field is not working.

```
df["CREATED DATETIME"] = df["CREATED ON DATE"] + df["CREATED AT TIME"]
```

How to combine these 2 columns as 1 datetime field "CREATED DATETIME"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df["CREATED DATETIME"] = df["CREATED ON DATE"] + pd.to_timedelta(df["CREATED AT TIME"])
```

If objects python times in column, convert it to `string`s before:

```
df["CREATED DATETIME"] = (df["CREATED ON DATE"] + 
                          pd.to_timedelta(df["CREATED AT TIME"].astype(str)))
```

Comment: Thanks but this ends in: ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>

Comment: @JeroenDeRooy - Ok, so it means use second solution.